# NDK on ARM-9 and ARM-11

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, codec, android-ndk-r5

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html)

The latest release of the NDK supports the following instruction sets:
    ARMv5TE, including Thumb-1 instructions (see docs/CPU-ARCH-ABIS.html for more information) ARMv7-A, including Thumb-2 and VFPv3-D16 instructions, with optional support for NEON/VFPv3-D32 instructions (see docs/CPU-ARM-NEON.html for more information) x86 instructions (see docs/CPU-X86.html for more information) MIPS instructions (see docs/CPU-MIPS.html for more information)

.........

Does that mean if I run my app on a mobile phone having ARM-9 or ARM-11, there will be some performance penalty?

Comment: ARMv7 is newer then ARM-9 or ARM-11... confusing I know, but ARM-11 is actually ARMv6 and ARM-9 is actually ARMv5